# Addressable Asset Systemで取得したAudioClips が再生されない

Tags: unity3d, unity2d

Addressable Asset System　で取得したAudioClipをAudioSourceに渡しても、再生されません。 PlayMode を Use Asset Databaseに設定すると正常に再生されますが、,  Use Existing Buildに変更すると再生されなくなります。
また、Windowsビルドでも再生されません。
コンソール上にはエラーメッセージは出ていません。
なにかお心当たりのことがありましたら何卒ご教示ください。

何か不足がありましたらコメントお願いします。
ネット上でも同現象の報告が見つからず、大変困っております。
どうぞよろしくお願いします。

#### 試したこと

1. Addressable Groupのウインドウ上でNew Build > Default Build Script from
   Addressable を実行しました。また、 Clean Build も実行しました。 いずれも状況改善しませんでした。
2. AudioClipの取得自体に失敗しているのかと考え、DebugLogでコンソールに取得したClipの名前を表示してみました。 しかし、正常なクリップ名がログに表示されました。
   同じタイミングでEditor上のAudioSourceにAudioClipが渡っているか確認すると、Noneのままになっていました。
   AudioClipらしきデータは取得できているが、 audiosource.clip = clip
   の設定が正常に完了できないものと考えています。
3. AssetBundleCompression のセッティングをUnCompressedに変えてみましたが、変化はありません。

#### 実行環境

Unity Version 2021.3.10f1
Addressables Version 1.19.19

#### 該当箇所のコード

main.cs

```
public async UniTask ExecuteAsync(CallInstReference reference, InstRunner runner, CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    AudioClip clip = await Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<AudioClip>(clipAddress.Get());
    reference.world.callSoundManager.PlayVoice(clip, duration );
        Addressables.Release(clip);
    }
```

callSoundManager.cs

```
    public void PlayVoice( AudioClip clip , float duration = 0.2f , bool loop = false)
    {
        Debug.Log(clip.name + " voiceStart"); //currect clip name displayed.
        VoiceTrack.clip = clip; //no clip attached the audioSource in Editor
        VoiceTrack.loop = loop;
        VoiceTrack.Play();
        VoiceTrack.DOFade(1f, duration);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
直接

```
AudioClip clip = await Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<AudioClip>(clipAddress.Get());
```

と待ち受けていましたが、handle を取り出して別途Taskを待ち受ける必要があったようです。お騒がせしました。

以下コードで正常動作しました。

```
AsyncOperationHandle<T> handle = Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<T>(key);
await handle.Task; 
if (handle.Status ==AsyncOperationStatus.Succeeded) result = handle.Result;
```